Incorrect name of the sitename coming under Google search
I am a research student. I have a built a website for a conference. This is the third edition of the conference.
Today when I searched the keyword "ICSP 2024", the search result is showing the correct link but wrong site name at the top of the link. I have attached the screenshot for the reference.
It is still showing ICSP 2021. How to deal with this? Thank you.


To fix this you should use schema.org markup that states the name of your website. Please have a look at the corresponding documentation provided by Google.
I suggest to use only ICSP as name, to avoid running into the same issue next year.
Hope this helps.
